# Xsl FO + PDF generation by reading XML

Tags: xsl-fo

Not able to have borders for cells that have null values using XSL FO.I tried with border-collapse and empty-cells.Not sure if i used them properly.

XSL-FO Example

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block align="center" border-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-right-width="1pt" border-left-width="1pt"
        border-bottom-width="0pt" border-color="black" padding="0pt">
        <xsl:value-of select="Jan"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Can you post a small example of your XSL-FO?

Comment: <fo:table-cell>
                      <fo:block align="center" border-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-right-width="1pt" border-left-width="1pt" border-bottom-width="0pt" border-color="black" padding="0pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Jan"/>
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the attributes from `fo:block` up to the `fo:cell`...

```
<fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-right-width="1pt" border-left-width="1pt" border-bottom-width="0pt"
    border-color="black" padding="0pt">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="Jan"/>
    </fo:block>                             
</fo:table-cell>
```

If that doesn't work, try adding a zero width space to your `xsl:value-of`...

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(Jan,'&#x200B;')"/>
```

Comment: Your issue is impossible to diagnose without exposing more of the content. EXAMPLE: You have a table that contains one cell and one column and the only thing in it is ... nothing ... you will get nothing (just as you asked in FO). You need to post the whole table at a minimum to begin diagnosing the issue,

Answer (score 0):

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" border="solid">
<fo:table-column column-width="0.6in" border="solid"/>
<fo:table-row border="inherit">
```

The borders can be applied for  where ever required.Before passing value to xsl .check for null value and pass empty string if value is empty